# How to create and fetch custom URL for advanced search?

Tags: search

I like to search for very specific parameters, the resulting URL's look like this:

http://localhost/crm4/civicrm/contact/search/advanced?_qf_Advanced_display=true&qfKey=5aa3233e9b46c807b76a536cee723745_4637

Now I would like to save that URL and create a menu link for it, but it keeps changing dynamically...

How can I do that? Save it as a custom search? [image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SOLVED]

Solution is over here:

http://brunovincent.net/data/how-to-add-custom-search-url-links-to-civi-crm-advanced-search/

Comment: i added a link to the PR that I was referring to

Comment: This link is dead - could you provide a brief summary of the technique? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jon, sorry, I change the link now, let me know if it helped ;)

Comment: page not found :(

Answer (score 2):

Normally if you want to save an Adv Search you save it as a Smart Group

we have done a lot of work for a client to make various parameters available for links to preload on Adv Search - the PR is here - https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12455

Comment: Let me know how when you can please ;)